Django. Объединение полей ManytoMany для последующей сортировки
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть два класса Book и Author. У книги может быть как много авторов, так и ни одного.
class Author(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, blank=True)

Соответственно требуется объединить значения полей 'name' из Author и 'title' из Book для корректной сортировки по алфавиту и фильтрации по первой букве для алфавитного списка:

Сахаров С., Солевой С. Судьбы родины.
Сборник статей
Суворов Г.М. Ох уж эти сказки

Пробовал "Concat" во 'views.py', но он игнорирует пустые поля в author и ставит книги без автора в самый верх списка.
Объединял через функцию в 'models.py' и в шаблоне сортировал через |dictsort:"", но сортирует криво при включенной пагинации, да и не хочется логику в шаблоне держать.
В общем, прошу совета. Спасибо

Нужно было все-таки действовать через Concat во views.py, но обращаться не к полю author модели Book, а идти через модель Author к его полю name.
books_list=Book.objects.annotate(FullTitle=Concat('author__name', 'title')).order_by('FullTitle')

Один нюанс: у книг с несколькими авторами создаются дубликаты (в количестве, равном количеству авторов). Но для алфавитного каталога так и должно быть - сортируются они каждый в свою букву. Т.е. книга "Иванов И., Петров П. История игрушек" будет лежать и в букве И, и в букве П.

Примерно так:
for book in Book.objects.all():
  result_str = ', '.join(
   [book.autor.all().values_list('name', flat=True)]
  ) + ' ' + book.name
  print(result_str)

Для удобства, в модель book можно добавить проперти:
@property
def autors_str(self):
  return ', '.join([self.autor.all().values_list('name', flat=True)])


А как потом отправить это в order_by?

Не помню точно, но можно же попробовать передать в order_by('autors_str')

Понял, буду пробовать. Спасибо

Здесь принято говорить спасибо, путем голосования за ответы )

Да что-то всё равно не работает. Ошибка "Cannot resolve keyword 'autors_str' into field."

Вообще, как я понимаю, чтоб с пагинацией нормально работало надо через class Meta, ordering делать. Но как приладить туда ваш цикл, ума не приложу
